# Why is SDL_DisplayFormat crashing?

Tags: windows, crash, mingw, sdl

I have narrowed it down to SDL_DisplayFormat after probing. I compiled with `g++ -o test.exe test.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL2_image` on a windows machine, using msys, and ran the executable; then `echo $?` returned 3...

```
int main( int argc, char **args ) {
    int status = SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    if ( status == -1 ) return 4;

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( W_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT, BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE );
    if ( screen == NULL ) return 44;

    SDL_Surface *loaded_surface = IMG_Load( "./res/figure.png" );
    if ( loaded_surface == NULL ) return 444;

    SDL_Surface *background = SDL_DisplayFormat( loaded_surface );
    return 5;
    if ( background == NULL ) return 4444;

    SDL_FreeSurface( loaded_surface );

    SDL_BlitSurface( background, NULL, screen, NULL );

    SDL_Flip( screen );
    SDL_Delay( 2000 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works fine on my system, when the file given to `IMG_Load()` exists. Check if the file `./res/figure.png` exists or not.

Comment: Yes, it does.  The directory where the executable is in contains a directory called res/ in which figure.png exists...

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: [can i use SDL-1.2.15 with SDL2-image extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368573/can-i-use-sdl-1-2-15-with-sdl2-image-extension)

`SDL2_Image` is not compatible with `SDL 1.x`, **You should upgrade to `SDL 2`.**